# Is the emmeans R package performing causal inference G-computation?

Tags: causality, lsmeans, doubly-robust-estimator

So I am trying to get an understanding of causal inference and how it differs from the usual contrasts. I regularly use the emmeans package in R, and I am wondering when the function emmeans() mentions it has averaged over the covariates is this essentially performing G-computation? At least for regular OLS or identity link GLM models it seems like that

One possible difference I see is that G-computation takes place on the response scale, so I wonder if you use the transform argument in emmeans when working with GLMs with a non-identity link, then would it be performing the G-computation? It seems like it does the delta method to convert the SEs to the response scale from the link scale.

And then if I modeled the treatment probability, inverted it, and used it as a covariate in a model, and then used emmeans -- would this be doubly robust estimation?

As my reference I am using the book here https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/causal-inference-book/ pages 163-167.

Edit 09/07/22: Anyone wondering about the connection --it is written about here https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/gformula.html. The marginaleffects package can do this

Comment: I don't really understand what `emmeans` does, but I was able to replicate g-computation results for linear models (you need to specify `type = "prop"` in the call to `contrasts()`, though). For logistic regression models, I could not get the results to agree. I would recommend not using `emmeans` for g-computation. The `stdReg` package does a good job for most purposes and provides correct standard errors.

Comment: As emmeans developer, I do understand what it does but am not an expert on causal inference so not so sure of that. It does seem that you might want to look at the cov.reduce argument (see help for ref_grid), which does provide some flexibility in setting covariates at their predicted values from another model. See also the "framing" example in the vignettes. I have tried to document things pretty clearly and the vignettes n general should help.

Comment: There is nothing inherently causal about the output of a linear, generalized linear, mixed or any other kind of model. The thing that makes an estimate causal comes from assumptions about the setting that are external to the statistical model. This means that there is no way that R (or anything else) could do causal inference without you knowing about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Re-reading your question, my understanding is that you are asking if `emmeans()` does G-computation as part of what it *ordinarily* does. And based on my very limited understanding of causal models and G-computation, I would say the answer is *NO*. That is simply because we don't treat covariates in any special way. For a numerical covariate, the default action is to compute its mean and use that as a reference value for all subsequent estimates, regardless of whether it is regarded as a mediator or not. We just treat it as a direct effect.

There may be some options in `emmeans()` that do allow the user to treat covariates in a different way. For example, we can fit a model `y ~ treat + M` where `treat` is a treatment and `M` is a mediator. Then suppose we subsequently do

```
emmeans(model, "treat", cov.reduce = M ~ treat)
```

This instructs `emmeans` to *not* use the average value of `M`, but rather to use `lm()` to fit the model `M ~ treat` (with the same dataset) and use its predictions for the value of `M`. In that way, the reference value of `M` is different for each treatment level. This is equivalent to creating a covariate `C` that is equal to the residuals of the `M ~ treat` model, fitting the model `y ~ treat + C`, and using `emmeans()` in the ordinary way by using `C`'s mean (which is zero) as the reference value. Perhaps this is similar to what G-computation does -- I am not sure, but perhaps someone else can shed some light on this. But at least it does something special with covariates thought to be mediators, and that seems more akin to what is needed in causal inference.

### Addendum

A comment to this answer suggests doing something like `emmeans(model, "treat", cov.reduce = FALSE, weights = "prop")` but that this is very inefficient as it creates a huge reference grid. I believe that the following may do the same thing:

```
emmeans(model, "treat", submodel = ~ treat)
```

The above puts a linear constraint on the estimates whereby all the effects other than those of `treat` are replaced by predictions of those effects from the given submodel. See `vignette("xplanations", "emmeans")` for the gory details. But in words, what happens is that we are trying to obtain the predictions we would have obtained from the submodel, while still accounting for the reduction in error variance achieved by including the covariate in the model. I think this in fact does relate to some causal-inference methods, but I lack the depth of knowledge in that are to be sure.

In the case of mixed models and generalized linear models, the `submodel` constraint will not be quite the same as would be obtained by fitting the submodel with the same method. To accomplish this (or at least get closer), one can use a new feature in version 1.6.0 of **emmeans** to bring in covariate predictions from an external model. Suppose `model` was fitted using something like `model <- lmer(y ~ M + treat + (1|SUBJ), ...)`

```
Mmod <- lmer(M ~ treat + (1|SUBJ, ...)
Mpred <- function(grid)
             list(M = predict(Mmod, newdata = grid, re.form = ~ 0))

emmeans(model, "treat", cov.reduce = extern ~ Mpred)
```

This is like the original `cov.reduce = M ~ treat`, except it uses `Mmod` instead of `lm(M ~ treat)` to do the predictions of `M`.

Comment: Thanks, based on the causal inf reference above, page 164, it seems like the G computation (also called standardization) method in the binary treatment case essentially makes 2 additional copies of the dataset but deletes the Ys and changes the treatment to all 0 and all 1 respectively. Then it fits the model on the original dataset and gets predictions on the 2 copies, and the predictions are then averaged and then a difference is computed. 

So it seems like G-comp is giving `E(Y|T=1,X) - E(Y|T=0,X)` which looks very similar to a contrast to me, with covariates X averaged out.

Comment: So I found out that using the `cov.keep` argument in `ref_grid` and keeping the continuous variables at their value, then using `weights=proportional` in the call to `emmeans(grid,pairwise~T,weights=proportional)` seems to give the effect estimate as G-comp. But it can be computationally intensive because looks like the ref grid keeps unique values for the continuous variables. To do G-comp, what I need is to average the expected value *after*, and not set the covariate to its average before (so use the empirical distribution of the covariates basically). Wonder if there is a faster way?

Comment: Did you try your proportional weighting with`cov.reduce = M ~ treat`? That does not reduce M to its mean, but instead to different predicted values for each treat.

Comment: Yes, although that does not quite give the same results (though it is more efficient) as G comp since it makes an assumption of the relation between M and treat. Whereas `cov.keep` avoids this assumption. Say the copy of the data is stored in `newdata` and you have a binary treatment T. G comp is artificially setting `newdata$T=1` and then obtaining the prediction `predict(model,newdata)` and then taking the mean of this prediction to get the estimated mean for T=1. The challenge is getting SEs, p-vals  for this without bootstrap, which is what I was trying to use `emmeans` to do.

Comment: Well, I honestly don't understand how your strategy of keeping all the covariate values separate can have worked, other than by coincidence, because this does nothing to account for causal features. It's just expanding the reference grid and changing the weighting. See @dimitriyvmasterov's  comment on the OP, which I agree with.

Comment: I understand now it seems like the "causal" aspect of it is external to whatever method is used. So even G-comp by itself (though mentioned with causal inf) is *not* causal either w/o the various causal assumptions. Otherwise it seems just a fancier modern approach to contrasts which is more broadly applicable (even to regularized GLM or ML models).  I am just trying to replicate the numerical aspect of it. The primary difference is it keeps everything at the same value except the `T` and then takes the diff of the predicted `Yhat`. I wonder if it's possible to have this feature incorporated.

Comment: @Vattaka Please see my addendum. I had to make a couple of corrections to the external cov.reduce part as there were errors

Comment: This post was a while back, but just wanted to point out for anyone wondering how to do this, now the R marginaleffects package can do it https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/gformula.html. The difference to emmeans is that when nonlinear/interaction terms are present, it averages over the observed data and does not set continuous variables to their  mean.

Comment: @Vattaka FYI I have been looking at this recently and have added a `counterfactuals` argument to `emmeans` (actually `ref_grid`) whereby counterfactual predictions are computed for the factors named there. I think that is a step forward in the kind of analysis you are asking about. It's only on GitHub now but will be included in the next CRAN update.